# Jest spy fails for typeorm repository update

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm, ts-jest

I am trying to use jest to mock certain typeorm functions.

At the top level I declared `jest.mock('typeorm');`
with `let someEntityRepository: Repository<SomeEntity>;` where Repository is imported from `typeorm` and SomeEntity being my class.

However, when spying on certain functions of the repository, everything works except spying on the `update` function which throws this error: `Cannot spy the update property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

Here is the sample code, but only the line that spies on the update fails.

```
    find = jest.spyOn(someEntityRepository, 'find'); // works
    findOne = jest.spyOn(someEntityRepository, 'findOne'); // works
    findOneProvider = jest.spyOn(someEntityRepository, 'findOne'); // works
    update = jest.spyOn(someEntityRepository, 'update'); // does not work
    del = jest.spyOn(someEntityRepository, 'delete'); // works
    save = jest.spyOn(someEntityRepository, 'save'); // works
```

I have already checked that the `update` function exists in the `Repository` node module.

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using nestjs testing library(@nestjs/testing):

I got the same problem while doing unit test's for my personal project and the problem was really simple.

You are probably mocking your db methods(normally you dont want to actually call you db) and with that on mind you will need to put the `update` method on you mock.

```
{
      provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
      useValue: { save: jest.fn(), update: jest.fn(), findOneById: jest.fn() },
},
```

In my case update function was missing in the useValue property, making it not available on the userRepository used on `jest.SpyOn()`;